# How to align TD containing a div in a tr?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this page I would like to do tab likes 'divs'. But I can't manage to align the td, 'align' atribute on the 'td' didn't work nor 'text-align' attribute on the style css. Can anyone help me?

HTML:

```
 <table>
<tr>
<td id="principal" >
<table>
  <tr>
  <td id="menu">
            <ul id=nav>
    <li>
        <a href="pesquisa.php">Pesquisas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="cad_pesquisa.php" onclick="return !window.open(this.href,     'Produtos', 'width=750,height=300')"target="_blank">Cadastrar Pesquisa</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="provasdedesenvolvimento.php">Provas de Desenvolvimento</a>
    </li> 
</ul>
    </td>

    <td id="meio">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="titulo">Provas de Desenvolvimento</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="esquerda">
            <div id="aba" class="1">Escolher Provas</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="esquerda">
            <table class="invisivel" id="1" border="1px">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
                <div id="aba" class="2">Processo de     Fabrica&ccedil;&atilde;o</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="invisivel" id="2" border="1px">
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </td>

</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
    body{margin:0px;padding:0px;color:black;background-color:#fff;font-    family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:9px;}
            #principal{
              text-align:center;
        border:1px solid #CCC;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:900px;
        padding:10px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        height:auto;overflow:hidden;
        }
            #meio{
              float:right;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:720px;
        border:1px solid #999;
        background-color:#F7F7F7;
        padding:10px;
        }
            #titulo{
                border:1px solid #FC0;
                background-color:#FFF6BF;
                width:600px;
                height:20px;
                padding:5px;
                text-align:center;
                margin:0 auto;
                font-size:15px
                }
            #aba{
                border:1px solid SteelBlue;
                border-radius: 15px 15px 5px 5px;
                background-color: LightBlue;
                width:500px;
                height:20px;
                padding:5px;
                text-align:center;
                margin:0 auto;
                font-size:15px
                }
            #esquerda{
                text-align: left;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
      .invisivel{
                display:none;
            }
      #menu{
        float:left;
        width:150px;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6whoj9xz/1/

Comment: code in question, or no help. the fiddle's nice, but unless the cost is replicated here, we don't go "outside" to help.

Comment: Two questions: 
1) why are you using tables to lay this out?
2) what do you mean by 'align the td'? Can you explain further, maybe even offer some visual support?

Comment: @abigwonderful i want the cell to be left aligned, i'm using tables to solve a previous bug where i couldn't use 'div' 'onclick' JQuery function.

Comment: Are you want "Escolher Provas" this cell to be left aligned?

Answer (score 0):

You want to like this

```js
$("div").on('click', function() {
   var classe = $(this).attr("class");
    $("#"+classe).show();
    for(var i=0; i<4; ++i){
     if(i!=classe){
       $("#"+i).hide();
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
body{margin:0px;padding:0px;color:black;background-color:#fff;font-    family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:9px;}
            #principal{
              text-align:center;
        border:1px solid #CCC;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:900px;
        padding:10px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        height:auto;overflow:hidden;
        }
            #meio{
              float:right;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:720px;
        border:1px solid #999;
        background-color:#F7F7F7;
        padding:10px;
        }
            #titulo{
                border:1px solid #FC0;
                background-color:#FFF6BF;
                width:600px;
                height:20px;
                padding:5px;
                text-align:center;
                margin:0 auto;
                font-size:15px
                }
            #aba{
                border:1px solid SteelBlue;
                border-radius: 15px 15px 5px 5px;
                background-color: LightBlue;
                width:500px;
                height:20px;
                padding:5px;
                text-align:center;
           
                font-size:15px
                }
            #esquerda{
                text-align: left;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
      .invisivel{
                display:none;
            }
      #menu{
        float:left;
        width:150px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="principal" >
<table>
  <tr>
  <td id="menu">
            <ul id=nav>
    <li>
        <a href="pesquisa.php">Pesquisas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="cad_pesquisa.php" onclick="return !window.open(this.href,     'Produtos', 'width=750,height=300')"target="_blank">Cadastrar Pesquisa</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="provasdedesenvolvimento.php">Provas de Desenvolvimento</a>
    </li> 
</ul>
    </td>

    <td id="meio">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="titulo">Provas de Desenvolvimento</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="esquerda">
            <div id="aba" class="1">Escolher Provas</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="esquerda">
            <table class="invisivel" id="1" border="1px">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
                <div id="aba" class="2">Processo de     Fabrica&ccedil;&atilde;o</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="invisivel" id="2" border="1px">
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </td>

</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: just remove margin:0 auto; from #aba;